# FragmentTranscation within a RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a complex RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Given that my app is targeted at tablets there's more space that allows for more complexity in the UI. When the user clicks a button inside that ViewHolder, I have to display another RecyclerView inside the ViewHolder. Given that the secondary RecyclerView is only needed when the user presses the button I don't want to load it immediately but seperate it out into a Fragment that will only be loaded when the user clicks the button within the ViewHolder

In the XML for my ViewHolder I declared a Framelayout via:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/counter"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

I call the items that the primary RecyclerView displays `stack`. Unfortunately, when the user clicks on the button of the stack with the `id=5` the secondary Fragment for the secondary RecyclerView gets added to the ViewHolder for `id=1` that gets listed first in the primary RecyclerView.

```
customizationButtonView.setOnClickListener {
    val fragmentTransaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    if (customizationFragment==null){
        stack?.let{ stack ->
            fragmentContainer.tag = stack.id.toString()

            val frag = StackCustomizationFragment(stack)
            customizationFragment = frag
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, stack.id.toString())
        }
    }
    else{
        customizationFragment?.let { fragmentTransaction.remove(it) }
        customizationFragment = null
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

Even the tagging seems to be ignored. Is there another way I can tell the FragmentManager to load the Fragment in the correct `R.id.fragmentContainer`?

Comment: I found out that placing fragments inside the ViewHolder is a bad idea. When updating the data inside Room the RecyclerView frequently changes which ViewHolder gets bound to which item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an id to your view with

```
frameLayout.setId(uniqueId)
```

you would assign an ID to your view in the bind method, based on the position of the item being bound. You could use `position + PREDEFINED_OFFSET` for instance.

you would then inflate your layout in `position + PREDEFINED_OFFSET`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with `inflate`, do I have to call the normal inflate method on an inflater or can I work with the transactions?

Comment: I mean inflating your fragment into the container, with fragmentManager.replace(position + PREDEFINED_ID, fragment, tag)